# I am trying to store timestamp value in Oracle db using hibernate 3.4.6 and java 8. But only date is getting stored in db

Tags: oracle, hibernate, date, timestamp

I have tried @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) annotation above  Date type member variable. And created date object like

```
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2007-09-23 10:10:10.0");
Date dt= new Date(timestamp.getTime());
```

But in db only 2007-09-23 is getting stored and also datatype in DB is DATE. It should be TIMESTAMP..Kindly help

Comment: what is the column type in db???

Comment: Column which is getting created is of Type DATE

Comment: change to your type to datetime  in db and check

Comment: i have set hbm2ddl.auto property to create in hibernate.cfg.xml, i want to create table from java-hibernate

Comment: though i changed hbm2ddl.auto to update and changed type of column to TIMESTAMP in db manually and it worked. But I want to create column from hibernate java only

Comment: Check also version of JDBC drivers. Since version 12c they behave differently. Maybe the newer version of drivers does what you want if you used setDate.

Answer (score 0):

Use simpledateformat

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date dt=dateFormat.parse("2007-09-23 10:10:10.0");
```

Also make sure your POJO has

```
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "DATE", insertable = false)
    private Date dt;
```

Comment: I tried SimpleDateFormat snippet, with   @Column(name = "DATE", insertable = false) in POJO, it is entering null values. And with   @Column(name = "DATE", insertable = true), it is entering only date value in db not timestamp